# How to bind a modal to CTA Link of data source item in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

The client does not want to create and assign 20 modals on presentation details for different data source items on the listing page. How we can bind one modal to the data source location so that it can pick each data source item and display content in the pop-up window on clicking on the CTA link tagged on each data source item.

Comment: You mean to say, you need only one rendering where you will provide a data source item? and that data source will have the information of all the other data sources?

Comment: Yes right.I have used SXA Search Result component to build this listing page. So using search scope we find the items to display in search result.I have created Scriban variant to display the results.But now we have requirement to bind the CTA link to a modal.